# Django-nonrel on Appengine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

```
class BillList(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    billno = models.CharField(max_length=15)


class OrderDetails(models.Model):
    billno = models.ForeignKey(BillList)
    orderdetails = models.TextField()
```

`User` is the one within `django.contrib.auth.models`.

I need to retreive all `billno` of a particular user. How do I go about doing this simple query in Django-nonrel on Appengine?

If I do this:

```
iq = User.objects.filter(username = "name1")
BillList.objects.filter(username = iq)
```

Then I get an error: `DatabaseError: Subqueries are not supported.`

If I try this straight away `BillList.objects.filter(username = "restaurant1")`, then `ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'restaurant1'`

I'm sure it must be possible to go about doing this simple query! Any workarounds?

Comment: I think the filter is failing because you are not passing it a model instance to filter against, but a string that is part of the model. Try doing a get first to retrieve the model that represents "restaurant1" then passing that model instance to the filter.

Comment: If you see my first example, that's exactly how I tried it the first time around. I retrieved a `User` object corresponding to `name1` and then tried to filter `BillList` with that object. But it seems such type of queries are not supported!

Comment: No, that's not what you did. You retrieved a *queryset* of Users corresponding to name1, and tried to filter with that queryset. But that's not supported. Use `get` instead of `filter` when retrieving the User.

Answer (score 2):

The others are correct.  But, there may be a fundamental problem here with your understanding of the `ForeignKey`.  For example:

```
username = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

That's not really a "username" at all.  It is a user object.  More understandable would be something like:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The `User` object is what has the `username` property.  So to get a person's username, you would use"

```
BillList.objects.get(billno = 12345).user.username
```

Then, your queries become:

```
iq = User.objects.get(username = "name1")
my_list = BillList.objects.all().filter(user = iq)
```

Or, more directly:

```
my_list = iq.billist_set.all()
```